# ‘ionic serve’ is failing without an error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-cli

After resetting git head one commit back and confirming ionic updates, ionic serve is exiting on 'build dev started...' with NO error :/

I have tried removing `package.lock.json` and `node_modules` folder from project end installing again with `npm update` - problem not solved

Then I have found out that on the other ionic project, ionic is not working too, with same problem.

```
ionic serve
[WARN] No local CLI detected.
       Starting with CLI 3.6, the CLI must be installed locally to use local CLI plugins.

? Install now? Yes

> npm install --save-dev --save-exact ionic@latest
✔ Running command - done!
[OK] Installed Ionic CLI locally!

Please re-run your command.
ctibor:client lucky$ ionic serve
? Local plugin @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova has an update available (1.4.1 => 1.6.2)! Would you like to install it? Yes
> npm install --save-dev --save-exact @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova@latest
✔ Running command - done!
[OK] Updated @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova to 1.6.2! 
? Local plugin @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular has an update available (1.3.2 => 1.4.1)! Would you like to install it? Yes
> npm install --save-dev --save-exact @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular@latest
✔ Running command - done!
[OK] Updated @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular to 1.4.1! 
> npm dedupe
✔ Running command - done!
```

ionic serve

```
[INFO] Starting app-scripts server: --port 8100 --p 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --r 35729 --address localhost - Ctrl+C
       to cancel
[06:34:13]  watch started ... 
[06:34:13]  build dev started ... 
user:folder username$
```

ionic info

cli packages: (/Users/lucky/Documents/projects/bubuc/client/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.6.2
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.4.1
@ionic/cli-utils                : 1.7.0
ionic (Ionic CLI)               : 3.7.0
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.7
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.9.5
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b 
ios-deploy : 1.9.1 
ios-sim    : 5.0.13 
npm        : 5.3.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting whole machine fixed this issue!

**EDIT (14.aug.2017)**: I have found out that this is just collision of two 'ionic serve' processes. Since now it was no problem to have multiple instances of `ionic serve`, for example when I had two projects opened at same time. This issue raised after `Starting with CLI 3.6, the CLI must be installed locally to use local CLI plugins.` update. So from now, cancelling the other process is enough to fix the issue.